# Retrieve "Clean" Image Out Of ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I've Image stored in ImageView and after several processes (flip, rotate, fix color, etc) it's saved back as new file. However, I just realize that when I just load into ImageView and soon after that directly save the result, I got different result. Take a look at attached image for reference.

**image source**
[image]

**image result**
[image]

Here's how I extract image from ImageView:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
+ File.separator + bufferPath;
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

selectedImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedImage.getDrawingCache());
selectedImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

imageFile = new File( filePath );

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

Is there any workaround to make resulting image the same as source? different component, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold a backing `Bitmap` (originally the source) that you carry out your manipulations on.

Use the `ImageView` just to **show** this `Bitmap` - do not manipulate the post-scaled version that is held in the `ImageView`'s drawing cache.

Comment: hahaha, you're right, I should just use ImageView as display.